# What does p and e denote in exec family of calls?

Tags: process, system-calls, exec

`l` and `v` in exec calls denote whether the arguments are provided via list or `array(vector)`. I read it somewhere that `p` denotes the user's path and `e` denote the environment but did not understand what that means?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check [this Wikipedia link on Exec function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(computing)#C_language_prototypes) and [this link on Starting a process with the exec() calls](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.getting_started%2Ftopic%2Fs1_procs_Starting_with_exec_spawn.html)

e – An array of pointers to environment variables is explicitly passed to the new process image.

> The "e" suffix versions pass an environment to the program. An
>   environment is just that—a kind of "context" for the program to
>   operate in. For example, you may have a spelling checker that has a
>   dictionary of words. Instead of specifying the dictionary's location
>   every time on the command line, you could provide it in the
>   environment:

l – Command-line arguments are passed individually (a list) to the function.

> For example, if I want to invoke the ls command with the arguments -t,
>   -r, and -l (meaning "sort the output by time, in reverse order, and show me the long version of the output"), I could specify it as
>   either.

p – Uses the PATH environment variable to find the file named in the path argument to be executed.

> The "p" suffix versions will search the directories in your PATH
>   environment variable to find the executable. You've probably noticed
>   that all the examples have a hard-coded location for the executable:
>   /bin/ls and /usr/bin/spellcheck. What about other executables? Unless
>   you want to first find out the exact path for that particular program,
>   it would be best to have the user tell your program all the places to
>   search for executables. The standard PATH environment variable does
>   just that.

v – Command-line arguments are passed to the function as an array (vector) of pointers.

> The argument list is specified via a pointer to an argument vector.

As mentioned in the other answer, [this link on Unix System Calls](http://www.di.uevora.pt/~lmr/syscalls.html) is also equally awesome for further reading.

Comment: @sekhar suman : Where are these environment variables stored? In the kernel?

Comment: @saurav1405-Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532155/linux-where-are-environment-variables-stored), you need to look for environ file in your user specific process for getting to know the environment variables applicable to that process. Like, /proc/<pid>/environ and read it's contents.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.di.uevora.pt/~lmr/syscalls.html, the suffixes indicate the type of arguments:

```
    l  argn is specified as a list of arguments.

    v  argv is specified as a vector (array of character pointers).

    e  environment is specified as an array of character pointers.

    p  user's PATH is searched for command, and command can be a shell program
```

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on this site.  Could you quote some relevant part from the link?

Comment: @yaegashi I have already modified my answer... Thanks for your suggestion